# Hybris new Solr Index

Tags: java, solr, sap-commerce-cloud

I've created my own SolrIndex with a new Composed Type (Category) , created some indexed types , attributes and indexed the data . My SOLR database is populated with the data , however , I don't know exactly how can I reach this data from Java. Is there any service or strategy that I can use ?

Comment: It's really pain point, I think Hybris should rewrite this layer in such a way so that one can easily enable any item type to leverage Solr search. Currently, to support a new item type, you have to override many classes as mentioned [here](https://answers.sap.com/questions/12761669/how-to-create-solr-index-for-custom-itemtype-and-h.html).

Comment: I'm following the post and i'm stuck with step 2 point 3 . Can you help me ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, I suggest you to follow the `SearchPageController` flow. Use the debugger and search for a product (from storefront search box) and be careful at all the beans that you're going through because you will need to override some default implementations for your new SolrIndex type. (I hope that you are familiar with their **converter** pattern because you will need to override some populators too and the .xml files are full of them). Let me now if you're facing any problems.

Comment: I'm following this answer https://answers.sap.com/questions/12761669/how-to-create-solr-index-for-custom-itemtype-and-h.html (the one that @HybrisHelp posted) and i'm stuck with step 2 point 3 . Can you help me ?

Comment: Can you start a chat conversation with me? Or post here your error / problem.

Comment: I've created a chat